# Regex for listing words start and ends with symbol

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

my file content has token words starts and ends with symbol @. there could also be two pairs in single line.

eg.

```
line1 ncghtdhj @token1@ jjhhja @token2@ hfyuj.
line2 hjfuijgt @token3@ ghju
line3 hdhjii@jk8ok@token4@hj
```

how do i get list of tokens...like

```
[token1,token2,token3,jk8ok,token4]
```

using `python re`

tried ...

```
mlist = re.findall(r'@.+@', content)
```

not working as expected, file content has token words starts and ends with symbol @. there could also be two pairs in single line.

Comment: Correct that there are no whitespaces before the first `@` and after the last `@` of `token4`?

Comment: Why not match `jk8ok`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thats the issue... need to ignore that jk8ok, which is not possible. so at least include that and also include token4.

Comment: @finswimmer yeah. no white space before, after token4

Comment: @Codesiddhar How would you differentiate between token and jk8ok. Do you want to match token literally? Is there any logic to it? See https://regex101.com/r/lvd4RF/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird , exactly.. i have no logic or option to differentiate. so let it be in my output list. will search and find in my token lookups to identify it as invalid. but re required is to identify tht line as two possible tokens. ( also updated the expected list)

Comment: @Codesiddhar That option is in my answer https://regex101.com/r/5uAiVF/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `jk8ok` can also be a match and there should be no spaces in the token you might use a negated character class with a capturing group and use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is an `@`

```
@([^\s@]+)(?=@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5uAiVF/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dqWFXA)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"@([^\s@]+)(?=@)"

test_str = ("line1 ncghtdhj @token1@ jjhhja @token2@ hfyuj. \n"
    "line2 hjfuijgt @token3@ ghju \n"
    "line3 hdhjii@jk8ok@token4@hj")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Result

> ['token1', 'token2', 'token3', 'jk8ok', 'token4']

If the tokens should be on the same line and spaces are allowed, you might use

```
@([^\r\n@]+)(?=@)
```

If you only want to match token followed by a digit:

```
@(token\d+)(?=@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvd4RF/1)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to separate the words with `@` on the beginning and end. And then you can filter out the words between the `@`.

```
with open("filename", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

lines_string = " ".join(lines)

# Seperating the words with @ on the beginning and end.
temp1 = re.findall("@([^\s@]+)(?=@)", lines_string)

# Filtering out the words between the @s.
temp2 = list(map(lambda x: re.findall("\w+", x), temp1))

# Flattening the list.
tokens = [val for sublist in temp2 for val in sublist]
```

Output:

```
['token1', 'token2', 'token3', 'jk8ok']
```

I have used the regex as mentioned by @The fourth bird